# RUSLE - LS - Factor - "Catchment Area"

Tags: saga, rusle

Regarding to the SAGA GIS LS Factor module (http://www.saga-gis.org/saga_tool_doc/2.2.0/ta_hydrology_22.html), how should be executed the option with the "Desmet & Govers (1996)" method?
Despite the information provided, it isn't clear.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Leaving the link for answer, from SAGA GIS Forum:
https://sourceforge.net/p/saga-gis/discussion/790705/thread/695ccc2180/#a8b5.
Best regards